# Double backslash in connection string when connecting to SQL Server with pyodbc in Jupyter

Tags: python, sql-server, string, pyodbc

Background:

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise, using Jupyter Notebook to connect to SQL Server instance with Pyodbc

I'm able to connect successfully with `trusted_connection=yes`

where `server = '.\SQLEXPRESS'` (my local instance)

```
con_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={db};trusted_connection=yes;'
```

However, when I try to pass in credentials, which I will need when connecting to Prod/Test servers, I get an error that my username is not valid.

where `server = '.\SQLEXPRESS'` (my local instance) (which should still work with creds)

```
`username = '<domain>\<user>'`

con_string = `f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE{db};UID={username};PWD={password}'
```

Here is where the problem arises: I'm initiating the username as follow, to escape backslash:

```
username='domain\\user'
```

If I run a `print(username)`, I get `'domain\user'` as expected.

However when I run the same connection string as before, this time with the username and password, I get an error message from pyodbc that says:

> 'domain\user' does not exist.

Why is SQL Server treating the variable `username` as containing `'domain\\user'` instead of the `'domain\user'` that I'm expecting.

I have tried everything that I can think of to get a single backslash in there, nothing seems to work. From loading the values in as environment variables to "raw" strings, replacing, etc

Interestingly whenever I just get output for `username` aka without printing, I get `'domain\\user'`

Even more confounding is why does SQL Server not kick back an error for the `server`, I'm not even escaping the backslash there, i am simply passing in '.\SQLEXPRESS'

I appreciate any insight into this issue.

Comment: Without using F string variables, does that connection string work if user name is hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this connection string:

```
con_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE{db};UID={username};PWD={password}'
```

UID is a SQL Auth login or database user.  Not a Windows user.  To use a Windows/AD identity you must use `trusted_connection=yes`.  And run the program as the target user or install a credential to use that user's credentials in NTLM authentication.  Or run your program with `runas` or `runas /netonly`.